# Django - Login User without model

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to implement an SSO login, deriving all the authorization rights from saml response:

```
class SAMLServiceProviderBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, saml_authentication=None):
        if not saml_authentication:  # Using another authentication method
            return None

        if saml_authentication.is_authenticated():
            attributes = saml_authentication.get_attributes()
            user = User(username=saml_authentication.get_nameid())
            user.first_name = attributes['givenName']
            user.last_name = attributes['sn']

        return None
```

in views I got something like

```
...
user = authenticate(saml_authentication=auth)
login(self.request, user)
...
```

`login` fails because of the missing `save()` method. The only way would be to inherit from `User` and override the `save` method. Trying this, I got the next errors with `is_authenticated`, `get_and_delete_messages`, and so on

Is there an easy way to insert a user object into session, without saving the user to database?

Something like:

```
request.session['user'] = authenticate(saml_authentication=auth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess should be possible with some limitations, eg. you cannot save your data with a user being a FK.

I have tried this myself, I suspect that you can dynamically create a user instance in the `authenticate()` method just don't call `user.save()`, or overwrite the `save()` method to do nothing.

You might also need to hook up the user record between requests, so you might need to write your own serializer for the user and load that construct the user instance back from session.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that Django's session objects are required for the authentication backend. i.e. if you login, then Django needs to store a reference to this fact somewhere. Django generally uses it's database to do this, however, if you're not using a database with your app then you can look at caching sessions instead:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions

(I'm assuming you're not using a database judging by your question)

More importantly however, depending on your needs, you may need to look at creating / configuring, a custom User Model in order to get your backend to work:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model